# Adding .dds image to webpage

Tags: html, css

Just a simple question: how do I add a .dds image to my webpage?

I have a folder like this:

[image: My folder contains a .html file and .dds file]

It contains a .html file and .dds file. This is the code in csstest.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<img src="btn-border-normal.dds">
</body>
</html>
```

But when I run csstest.html, it always gives me this:

[image: Why does it give me a broken image]

Why does it give me a broken image? How do I fix it?

---

I also tried this:

```
<div style="background:url(btn-border-normal.dds);">test</div>
```

It just gives me a plain "test":

[image: Just the word test]

Comment: I'm not sure if browsers are able to open `dds` files. Is there any reason to use this format instead of `png`?

Comment: @panther I'm making a site that involves the use of images from a game, that only come in `dds` files. I tried to convert all of them to `png` but for some of the images, they just became white. I am using Google Chrome by the way.

Comment: Well, you might want to look for another converter, .dds is not supported in browsers.